# How to install a mock library into a unit test in Angular? I want to install sinon-chrome into a spectator test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, google-chrome-extension, angular-spectator

I am working on a Google Chrome extension which is written in angular and I need to write unit tests for components that make use of the Chrome API. I found a library that I believe will do the job.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-chrome

However, I do not have enough experience with Angular to know how exactly to put the library into use. The [usage section](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-chrome#usage) says that I need to require the value in a constant, but I have no idea how or where that would go. Does that go in the unit test? Does that go in the `karma` file? What is the `global.chrome` that is found in [the examples.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-chrome#examples)

The code for my unit test. It otherwise runs fine except for this chrome mock issue.

```
const angularFireAuthMock = {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
    onAuthStateChanged: () => {},
};
 
describe('AppComponent', () => {
    let spectator: Spectator<AppComponent>;
    const createComponent = createComponentFactory({ component: AppComponent, mocks: [FirestoreService], providers: [{
        provide: AngularFireAuth, useValue: angularFireAuthMock,
    }] });
 
    beforeEach(() => {
        spectator = createComponent();
    });
 
    it('should create the app', () => {
        expect(spectator.component).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

`AppComponent` is where the Chrome

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you simply to check existing examples.

Go to their github: https://github.com/acvetkov/sinon-chrome

On the right side you can see "Used by". Go there: https://github.com/acvetkov/sinon-chrome/network/dependents?package_id=UGFja2FnZS0xMzc4MTk5MA%3D%3D

Then go to repo by repo and search in the search bar for "sinon-chrome" (without quotes)

This should show you how others use the package, and, I hope, it brings light on your question.

Comment: Well, I am dumb. Thank you.

Comment: Have you solved the issue or not? We can find a solution if it is still needed.